# overlay button menu javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I have a menu button "start". when I click on start, an overlay menu drops down with two circular buttons:
Fruits and veggies

Now, I want to click fruits and have the fruits and veggie button disappear and about 9 buttons appear on the overlay for 9 differnt fruits..

how would I do that?

```js
/* Open when someone clicks on the span element */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";

}


/* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <!-- Overlay content -->
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <button class="btn btn-circle overlay-icon" onclick='openNavTwo()'>Fruits</button>
    <div id="innerNav" class="overlay">
      <button class="btn btn-circle overlay-icon">Apple</button>
      <button class="btn btn-circle overlay-icon">Apple</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-circle overlay-icon" onclick=''>Veggies</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to at least attempt to solve the problem.  Can't just ask for us to implement it for you.

Comment: Im not even sure where to start. can you provide a hint please?